# Hook-up a MethodInfo to a delegate field (FieldInfo)

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

Simple case:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public Action<double> MyAction;
}

public class AnotherClass
{
  public void MyAction(double value)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

As I get both `AnotherClass.MyAction(..)` method and `MyClass.MyAction` delegate through reflection, I end up with a pair of MethodInfo/FieldInfo classes where I can't hookup the method to the delegate. Also I get both the method/delegate names from a string, I can't access the instance fields/methods without reflection. Can anyone give me a hand in this, or is this sort of a hook-up possible at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should look at `Delegate.CreateDelegate`, in particular:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(AnotherClass).GetMethod("MyAction");
FieldInfo field = typeof(MyClass).GetField("MyAction");


AnotherClass obj = // the object you want to bind to

Delegate action = Delegate.CreateDelegate(field.FieldType, obj, method);

MyClass obj2 = // the object you want to store the delegate in

field.SetValue(obj2, action);
```